# FBAR, just found about it. What to do?

Tags: united-states, taxes, fbar, foreign-income

Just found out about FBAR.

I have a pension investment in India (over $10K) that involves paying yearly premium (I've paid 8 of the 20 premiums) to it. It matures in 12 years and until then I do not receive any money out of it.

Do i just file an FBAR FinCEN form with a reason for filing late as 'Did not know i had to file'?

Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you didn't "forget" to report any income with regards to these accounts, you should be fine doing that. See more information and specific instructions on [this IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Delinquent-FBAR-Submission-Procedures).